# Get the direction (up/down) in which the user is scrolling on an IPad (touchmove event)

Tags: jquery-plugins, touch, gesture, jquery

I have following scenario:

I have a code, binded to the mousewheel event

```
$('#main').bind("mousewheel",function(ev, delta) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if(delta == '-1') {
        alert("The user is trying to scroll upwards");
    } else {
        alert("The user is trying to scroll down");
    }
});
```

I then included this [Plugin](http://furf.com/exp/touch-punch/) which provides the use of Iphone/Ipad touch events.
Look at following code:

```
$('#main').bind('touchmove', function(event) {
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to alert the direction in which the user is scrolling. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this awesome library.

```
jQuery('#swipe').bind('swipeup',eventHandler);
jQuery('#swipe').bind('swipedown',eventHandler);
```

More info: http://jgestures.codeplex.com/